# PHPmailer is sending mail twice

Tags: phpmailer

This script results in the email being send twice (not always). I have read that it could be the browsers fault, so Ive run chrome without the extensions. Still the same..
The subject line holds a random number, so I can see it's the same mail.
So I have the same number in my inbox twice.

Is there a browser that is safe to send mails in bulk (mailing) via PHPmailer?

Here is my code (which is not the problem probably)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION[$reciever]))
    {
       $_SESSION[$reciever] = 1;
     




require "mail_inhoud.php";                          // <== IMPORTANT INCLUDE

$maand = date('Ym'); // 202103
$datum = date('Ymd'); // '20210406'
$datum_tijd = date('Ymd H:i'); // '20210406'

$maand_ENG = 'March'; 
$teller = 1;



                    

     
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL FROM EMAILS_TESTBANK") or die(mysql_error());      

              //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead

            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
            //$mail->isSMTP(); 
            $mail->Mailer = 'sendmail'; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->Host = 'xxxxxx';
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->Username   = "xxxxx" ;  
            $mail->Password   = "xxxxxx"; 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
            $mail->setFrom('lucas.tessens@mers.be', 'MERS Antique Books Antwerp');
            $mail->Sender = 'bounced@mers.be'; 
            $mail->addReplyTo('lucas.tessens@mers.be', 'MERS Antique Books Antwerp'); 
            
                 
            $mail->Subject = 'Test Mail ' . rand();
            
            
            $ONDERWERP =  "Catalogue for $maand_ENG";
            $mail->Encoding = 'base64';

            $today = date('Ymd'); 




      if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
          

                
                    $email = $row['EMAIL'];
                    $email_user = $row['EMAIL'];


                    /* We stellen de INHOUD OP */
                    $message = "";
                    $message .= "<html>";
                    $message .= "<body>";

                    $message .= "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
                    $message .= "<tr><td align='center' style='width:600px'>";

                    $htmlContent = file_get_contents("$maand/INTERNATIONAAL.html");
                    $message .= $htmlContent;
                    $message .= "<br><br>";
                    $message .= "<div style='text-align:center'>";
                    $message .= "<span>This email was sent to $email</span> | <a href='https://www.mers.be/unsubscribe.php?EMAIL=$email' target='new' style='color:#666; text-decoration:none'>Unsubscribe</a>";
                    $message .= "<br><br>";
                    $message .= "<div style='visibility:hidden !important; opacity:0 !important; display:none !important' >";
                    $message .= "<img style='visibility:hidden !important' src='https://www.mers.be/backend/MAILING_NEW/mailcheck.php?user=$email&subject=$ONDERWERP'>";
                    $message .= "</div>";
                    $message .= "</div>";

                    $message .= "</td></tr>";
                    $message .= "</table>";
                    //$message .= $teller;

                    $message .= "</body>";
                    $message .= "</html>";
                    
                    $body = $message; 
                    
                    $mail->msgHTML($body);
                    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; 

                    
                        $raw_check = mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL FROM EMA_CONTROLE WHERE EMAIL = '$email_user' AND DATE = '$today'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                        
                       if(mysql_num_rows($raw_check) > 0){
                        // DO NOTHING, EMAIL WAS ALREADY SENT
                            echo 'EMAIL ALREADY SENT<br>';
                        }else{
                            echo 'NOT YET SEND<br>';
                            $mail->addAddress($email, 'Receiver name');
                            $mail->send(); // SEND EMAIL
                            $mail->clearAddresses();
                            $mail->clearAttachments();

                            echo 'Message sent to :  (' . htmlspecialchars($row['EMAIL']) . ')<br>';
                            //Mark it as sent in the DB
                            $OND = "NEW ARRIVALS MARCH DEEL 1";

                            mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8'); 
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `MAILING_VERZONDEN` 
                            (`DATUM`, `EMAIL`, WELKE_MAILING, `TAAL`, `RECEIVER`) VALUES 
                            ('$datum_tijd', '$email','$OND', 'INTERNATIONAAL', 'KLANT' )") or die(mysql_error());

                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `EMA_CONTROLE` ( `EMAIL`, `DATE`) VALUES ('$email','$today')") or die(mysql_error());
                        }
                        
                    

echo $teller; echo '<br>';
  $teller++;
  
}
}




    }
  else{
        echo "doing it more than once";
     }

$conn = null;
$con = null;
exit;
```

I tried sending this mailing many times.
I expect it to arrive once, not 2 or more times

Comment: Do you use a `GET` form-action to send the email-address? 

Answer (score 0):

Docs on diagnosing this are [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Diagnosing-email-sending-twice-(or-more)). Using a random string in the subject is to check whether the script is being called more than once, which doesn't seem to be your issue here.

I suggest *not* sending via `sendmail` (its' not clear why you think you need to do that), but use SMTP (i.e. don't comment out `isSMTP()`), as most of your code seems to want, and set debug output with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` so that you can see exactly what your script is sending to the server. For example, if your SQL is resulting in duplicate rows, it will cause your symptom.

You should not be using any `mysql_` functions; that extension is long obsolete, though that's not the problem here.

Comment: Could it be that the browser that the PHP-file runs in causes problems?

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser, so no. The only thing the browser could do is repeat the request, but that would be detected by the random subject trick you're already using.